# Cypher query aggregate sum of values

Tags: neo4j, sum, cypher, aggregate

I have a Cypher query that shows the following output:

```
+----------------
| usid  | count |
+----------------
| "000" | 1     |
| "000" | 0     |
| "000" | 0     |
| "001" | 1     |
| "001" | 1     |
| "001" | 0     |
| "002" | 2     |
| "002" | 2     |
| "002" | 0     |
| "003" | 4     |
| "003" | 2     |
| "003" | 2     |
| "004" | 4     |
| "004" | 4     |
| "004" | 4     |
+----------------
```

How can I get the below result with the condition **SUM(count) <= 9**.

```
+----------------
| usid  | count |
+----------------
| "000" | 1     |
| "001" | 2     |
| "002" | 4     |
| "003" | 8     |
+----------------
```

Note: I have used the below query to get the 1st table data.

```sql
MATCH (us:USER)
WITH us
WHERE us.count <= 4
RETURN us.id as usid, us.count as count;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you get your original data, so I will just use a WITH clause and assume the data is there:

```
// original data
WITH usid, count
// aggregate and filter
WITH usid, sum(count) as new_count
WHERE new_count <= 9
RETURN usid, new_count
```

Based on the updated question, the new query would look like:

```
MATCH (us:USER)
WHERE us.count <= 4
WITH us.id as usid, sum(us.count) as count
WHERE new_count <= 9
RETURN usid, count
˙˙˙
```

Comment: Thanks!. I have updated the question with the query which returns original data. Please check it once. I need the data as mentioned in the 2nd table. How should I modify the query?